# hitTest on subview returns nil in UIGestureRecognizerState.Began

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tableView (embedded in a nav controller) with a longPress gesture recognizer attached to it. When the user presses on the tableview for a period of time, a (modal) subview called coverView is presented. CoverView has multiple subviews called 'characterView'. As long as the longpress gesture is ongoing, the user can select a characterView. CoverView will be removed as soon as the user lifts the finger.

Question: I need to know which characterView is hit as soon as the coverView is presented, before the user moves the finger. This is my relevant code:

```
    func showCoverView (longpressgesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    var point = longpressgesture.locationInView(coverView) 

    switch (longpressgesture.state){

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:

        //coverView is added     
        navigationController?.view.addSubview(coverView)

        var hitTestView = coverView.hitTest(point, withEvent: nil)

        println("hittestview is \(hitTestView)")// returns NIL in most cases. Why?

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:

        var hitTestView = coverView.hitTest(point, withEvent: nil) 

        println("hittestview is \(hitTestView)")// returns a characterView. No problem here.

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

The problem is that the hitTest:withEvent returns nil in most cases (sometimes it randomly returns the correct view) as long as the touch hasn't moved yet. As soon as the user starts dragging, the state changes in 'changed' and the problem doesn't occur.

Does someone know the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, time to answer my own question. First of all: I used the 'point' variable that was assigned before coverView was added as a subview. When I logged the CGPoint, I discovered that the point was expressed in pixels instead of points. The locationInView method apparently only returns a valid point when the argument is a view that is actually added to the screen.

When I solved this, the hitTest returned the coverView itself, but not one of it's subviews (characterView).

So, part two was calling layoutIfNeeded on the coverView before doing the hitTest. This solved my problem and the hitTest now returns the correct view. Apparently there is something in the background preventing the subviews' subviews to be noticed when doing the hitTest on a new subview.

New code:

```
    func showCoverView (longpressgesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

var point = longpressgesture.locationInView(coverView) 

switch (longpressgesture.state){

case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:

    //coverView is added     
    navigationController?.view.addSubview(coverView)

    var firstPoint = longpressgesture.locationInView(coverView) //solution part A

    coverView.layoutIfNeeded() //solution part B

    var hitTestView = coverView.hitTest(firstPoint, withEvent: nil)

    println("hittestview is \(hitTestView)")// returns a characterView. Problem solved.

case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:

    var hitTestView = coverView.hitTest(point, withEvent: nil) 

    println("hittestview is \(hitTestView)")// returns a characterView. No problem here.

default:
    break
}

}
```